# Vectorizing for loop in Numpy

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

is there a way to vectorize this?

```
waveheight=zeros(10000)
for t in range(10000):
    for j in range(N_frequencysteps):
        waveheight[t] = waveheight[t] + (Abs_S_newwave[j] * cos (K[j] * x - (omega[j] * ((t*0.01) - TimeShift)) + TSi_omega[j] + arg_S_newwave[j]))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
waveheight = (Abs_S_newwave[:,None] * cos(K[:,None] * x - (omega[:,None] * ((arange(10000)[None,:]*0.01) - TimeShift)) + TSi_omega[:,None] + arg_S_newwave[:,None])).sum(axis=0)
```

This works if all arrays of length `N_frequencysteps` are 1-D numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

At least one step of vectorization would be not to iterate over the elements of `waveheight`:

```
waveheight=zeros(10000)
ts = arange(10000)
for j in range(N_frequencysteps):
    waveheight += (Abs_S_newwave[j] * cos(K[j] * x - (omega[j] * 
             ((ts*0.01) - TimeShift)) + TSi_omega[j] + arg_S_newwave[j]))
```

This assumes that all other variables are scalars.